# @font-face dose work on firefox and IE

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, font-face

Hi i have question here about @font-face. I have font need been used on my website. but it is only works on chrome, no luck on firefox and IE. so i search from internet and found the following code is working well on all the browses.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gradient';
    src:url("http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensanscondensed/v7/gk5FxslNkTTHtojXrkp-xF1YPouZEKgzpqZW9wN-3Ek.woff") format("woff"); 
    }
```

however once i download it and put it on my server, it is not work again:

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'Gradient';
        src:url("gk5FxslNkTTHtojXrkp-xF1YPouZEKgzpqZW9wN-3Ek.woff") format("woff"); 
    }
```

so i try to use url to include the woff file on my server but is is not work:

```
 @font-face {
        font-family: 'Gradient';
        src:url("http://mywebsite/mypath/gk5FxslNkTTHtojXrkp-xF1YPouZEKgzpqZW9wN-3Ek.woff") format("woff"); 
    }
```

anyone could explain why? same file on different server one is working well and the other is not.

thanks so much
jenny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox and IE don't allow you to pull in a font from another domain. Move the font files to the same folder the website is in, and they will work.

Comment: That's not entirely correct; the domain serving the WOFF font must supply an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header. Hit `F12` to check for an error message in the console to determine if this is the problem.

Comment: thanks for the help. anyway, i don't see any error in the console and the font file was downloaded successfully. i don't understand how come "http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensanscondensed/v7/gk5FxslNkTTHtojXrkp-xF1YPouZEKgzpqZW9wN-3Ek.woff" is working we, but"http://mywebsite/mypath/gk5FxslNkTTHtojXrkp-xF1YPouZEKgzpqZW9wN-3Ek.woff" is not?

Comment: Try running it through a webfont generator like: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator This should give you all of the correct code needed.